# Autoplay handler: wrong clipboard format?

Tags: c#, windows, com, interop, autoplay

I'm trying to implement a Windows Autoplay handler; according to the documentation and the examples I found, I'm supposed to query the `IDataObject` for the `"Autoplay Enumerated IDList Array"` clipboard format.

So I tried to do something like that:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "RegisterClipboardFormatW")]
public static extern uint RegisterClipboardFormat([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String format);

private const string CFSTR_AUTOPLAY_SHELLIDLISTS = "Autoplay Enumerated IDList Array";
private static readonly uint AUTOPLAY_SHELLIDLISTS = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_AUTOPLAY_SHELLIDLISTS);

...

public int Drop(IDataObject pDataObj, int grfKeyState, Point pt, ref DropEffect pdwEffect)
{
    var fmt = new FORMATETC
    {
        cfFormat = (short)AUTOPLAY_SHELLIDLISTS,
        ptd = IntPtr.Zero,
        dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
        lindex = -1,
        tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL
    };

    int hr = pDataObj.QueryGetData(ref fmt);
    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But `QueryGetData` always returns `S_FALSE` (and `GetData` throws, obviously). So I tried to enumerate the available formats with `EnumFormatEtc`: <strike>it returns only one format</strike> it returns 4 formats, none of which is the same as the one I passed to `QueryGetData` (`cfFormat` values are -16238, 15, -16378 and -16377). If I use the first format from `EnumFormatEtc`, instead of `AUTOPLAY_SHELLIDLISTS`, everything works fine, but I don't think it's the right way to do it...

Could someone explain what is going on? Am I using the wrong format?

EDIT: apparently the first format returned from `EnumFormatEtc` is `"Shell IDList Array"`; clearly I can work with that, but what happened to `"Autoplay Enumerated IDList Array"`?

Comment: Your second to last sentence is incomplete. Please complete it. Especially, you should answer why you don't want to use the solution you found when everything works fine. BTW: What is the actual `cfFormat`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I edited my question to add the relevant information. I thought there was only one format, because I was using EnumFormatEtc incorrectly; but there are actually 4 formats, and I don't know which one I'm supposed to use...

Comment: I don't see any official reference of this 'Autoplay Enumerated IDList Array' in MSDN (only MSDN mag or other non Microsoft articles). The official doc instead talks about a COM interface IHWEventHandler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx or am I missing something?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I followed [this MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301341.aspx) and [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15626/Implement-an-Autoplay-Handler). I'm only interested in volume-based devices, so I implement IDropTarget, not IHWEventHandler

Comment: Right, maybe it *was* fully supported back in XP days, but since you can't find any reference to CFSTR_AUTOPLAY_SHELLIDLISTS in Microsoft today's official documentation, you can't rely on it IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found a *much* easier way to do it, using the [`System.Windows.Forms.DataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataobject.aspx) class:

```
    public int Drop(IDataObject pDataObj, int grfKeyState, Point pt, ref DropEffect pdwEffect)
    {
        try
        {
            var dataObj = new DataObject(pDataObj);
            if (dataObj.ContainsFileDropList())
            {
                StringCollection files = dataObj.GetFileDropList();

                // Do something with files...

            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex));
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

No need for any low-level COM interop (except the `IDropTarget` interface declaration)...